# How to verify the new tab is opened or not in selenium cucumber js

Tags: node.js, selenium, cucumber

```
var parent = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
var windows = driver.getAllWindowHandles(); 
driver.switchTo().window(windows[1]);     
driver.close();                           
driver.switchTo().window(parent);       
driver.sleep(3000);
const text=await driver.getCurrentUrl();  
console.log("text"+text)
```

-I tried to fetch the newly opened tab URL but it is still pointing the Previous tab.Can anyone help me??Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are switching back to parent and then get the url. Perform the get url action right after switching to **windows[1]**